# Android BLE ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED not called for paired device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Android 4.4. I have 2 Bluetooth devices, one old-school Bluetooth and one BLE. They are both identical functionally as far as the data they transmit. They both have a single button that connects and transmits data when pressed.

I have Bluetooth permissions on and registered a BroadcastReceiver in my manifest, like so

```
...

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

...

<receiver
    android:name=".BluetoothBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

To test, I am simply logging the calls to onReceive in the BroadcastReceiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, intent.getAction());
}
```

Here is the problem: both of the devices are paired with the phone, but only the old-school Bluetooth device generates the ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED/ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED broadcasts when the button the Bluetooth device is pressed. Nothing happens when the BLE device tries to connect and transmit.

I am able to successfully connect and receive data from the BLE device if I am actively scanning for BLE connections using

```
mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
```

Do I have to explicitly scan for BLE devices to allow them to connect? Do BLE devices generate ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED/ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED broadcasts when not explicitly scanning for BLE devices? Or should they automatically connect if paired to the phone?

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer ? Stuck in the same situation like yours

Comment: @abhishek No, I never found an answer to my question. The solution I settled on was to run a service in the background that does a 1 second BLE scan every 30 seconds. These values were selected based on the advertising characteristics of my peripheral, and may not be helpful for your particular situation. Based on my testing, doing this periodic background scanning has a very small (<5% per 24 hr period on a Nexus 4) impact on battery life.

Comment: Thanks, i might as well try this once

Comment: Anyway <5% is really a lot for a Service that does really nothing... Did you find another smarter solution?

Comment: @StErMi Try active BLE scanning for what amounts to around 48 straight minutes and tell me what the battery life is like. See [this link](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service/wiki/Battery-Usage) which basically finds ~7.8% battery drop in 24 hours in the background while scanning for the same amount of total time as my implementation.

Android 'L' apparently supports a new, low-power, always on scanning mode (basically what the BLE implementation should have been in the first place). Unfortunately for all Android 4.3 and 4.4 users, they won't have access to this mode.

Comment: still no answer guys?

Answer (score -1):

`ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED/ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` broadcasts are only for BR/EDR (Classic Bluetooth), not for BLE.

For BLE you must work with the APIs and callbacks provided by the newest Android versions.

Comment: @bogdan-alexandru Could you provide a source of this information? Any Android docs or something?